# OpenCV Reflective Surface Problem (Pre-Process Text from Digital Screen)

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract, image-preprocessing

I'm working on a machine learning application for reading data from fuel pumps, so far I've gone ahead and created a pretty robust YOLOv5 Object Detection Model that can detect the regions that I want fairly accurately. But there is a problem, at certain times of the day there are *reflections on the digital screen* and I'm unable to use OpenCV pre-process it so that I can extract the numbers from the display.

**Check this Video to Understand (YOLOv5 Detection)**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3XjZ6Nw70j8

**Minimum Reproduceable Example**

Cars come and go and their reflection makes it really difficult to differentiate between the reigons for *digital-7* font that is used in these displays, you can check out the following repository to understand what I want as s result https://github.com/arturaugusto/display_ocr

[image: Example Image I encounter]

**Other Solutions I'm Open to:**

1. Since, this application is going to run 24/7 how should I deal with different times,
   perhaps create a database of HSV ranges to extract at different times.
2. Use a polarizing lens would it help in removing the reflections (any user's who have had previous experiences in deploying them).

Edit: I added the correct video ...

Comment: talk to the manufacturer of those pumps. they'll surely give you a way to read the data directly.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks. I'm really hoping on a polarizing lens, if it works then I'll be back in business. I'll post an update about that.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but as far as I know polarising lenses need to be calibrated for a certain distance. As objects move further or closer than a calibrated distance, the polarising lense will be less effective. Just something to keep in mind, you should be fine as I assume most of your iamges will be fairly close.

Comment: Why can you not process that image to give it more contrast. Seems like a simple issue.